# Combining graphic modeller Python output with another Python Script

Tags: python, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I created a model that takes my point shapelayer, creates polygons from these points using minimum bounding geometry then adds a field named 'Zonekey' to attribute table;

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing


class Mz_tool(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('addlayer', 'myLayer', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry], defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Result', 'Result', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
    # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
    # overall progress through the model
    feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(6, model_feedback)
    results = {}
    outputs = {}

    # Create categorized renderer from styles
    alg_params = {
        'CASE_SENSITIVE': False,
        'FIELD': 'Product',
        'INPUT': parameters['addlayer'],
        'STYLE': '',
        'TOLERANT': False
    }
    outputs['CreateCategorizedRendererFromStyles'] = processing.run('native:categorizeusingstyle', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Minimum bounding geometry
    alg_params = {
        'FIELD': 'Product',
        'INPUT': parameters['addlayer'],
        'TYPE': 3,
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['MinimumBoundingGeometry'] = processing.run('qgis:minimumboundinggeometry', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Zonekey
    alg_params = {
        'FIELD_LENGTH': 100,
        'FIELD_NAME': 'Zonekey',
        'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
        'FIELD_TYPE': 2,
        'INPUT': outputs['MinimumBoundingGeometry']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['Zonekey'] = processing.run('qgis:addfieldtoattributestable', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Drop field(s)
    alg_params = {
        'COLUMN': 'area',
        'INPUT': outputs['Zonekey']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['DropFields'] = processing.run('qgis:deletecolumn', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(4)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Drop field(s)
    alg_params = {
        'COLUMN': 'perimeter',
        'INPUT': outputs['DropFields']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['DropFields'] = processing.run('qgis:deletecolumn', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(5)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Drop field(s)
    alg_params = {
        'COLUMN': 'id',
        'INPUT': outputs['DropFields']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': parameters['Result']
    }
    outputs['DropFields'] = processing.run('qgis:deletecolumn', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    results['Result'] = outputs['DropFields']['OUTPUT']
    return results

def name(self):
    return 'mz_tool'

def displayName(self):
    return 'mz_tool'

def group(self):
    return ''

def groupId(self):
    return ''

def createInstance(self):
    return Mz_tool()
```

I have another Python code that I can use to fill my Zonekey with random strings requested from random.org's API.

```
import requests
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
count = lyr.featureCount()

reqData = {
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"generateStrings",
    "params":{"apiKey":"myapikeygoeshere",
    "n":(llen),                                                 #number of strings to be produced equals to feature count using llen
    "length":20,
    "characters":"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
    "replacement":True
    },
    "id":539
    }

response = requests.post('https://api.random.org/json-rpc/2/invoke',         
json = reqData)
response.raise_for_status()
json = response.json()
data = json['result']['random']['data']

lyr.startEditing()
i = 0
for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    f['Zonekey'] = data[i]
    lyr.updateFeature(f)
    i+=1
lyr.commitChanges()
```

Currently I am running the first script then proceed to the second one, but I am looking for a way to combine these two processes into one Python script that I can use from Processing toolbox.

How would I get the 'Zonekey' field created using the first script filled with the strings from the second script? Since I run them one by one I tried to add the entire second script to the first one, but I it didn't work. I also tried not exporting my model and using Advanced Python Field Calculator in the model to insert my code, but couldn't get it to work either.